# How to solve pylance server crashing in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Beginner here in coding/programming.

I'm doing the MOOC from Helsinki University. Using VS Code and the TMC plugin is a must because I admit my solutions through it.

Pylance server keeps on crashing every few days. I can't find a solution for it. Sometimes it works back without any intervention from me. But this time it has been not working since few days.

I copied the output into a google docs document since it's very long:
[error output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14R05a1K2gJCv6ijI8SlKicn7RiXMxvhJVOjh78BtC2M/edit?usp=sharing)

Could you please help me solve this issue? I'm using an M1 Macbook Air in case it makes a difference.

Thank you

Comment: 27 pages is too much error log and not enough information. Please condense the log to the relevant parts and include them in the question. Links can break, making the question useless. We also need more information on what you are doing when it crashes. Can you reproduce it? (How?) Please see [ask].

Comment: Note that there are specific issues circa the 2023.10.40 version of the Pylance extension. for a question specifically about those issues, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77390176/11107541

Answer (score 5):

> [Warn  - 4:28:20 PM] (4592) stubPath /Users/karim/Library/Application Support/tmc/vscode/mooc-programming-22/part04-01_hello_visual_studio_code/typings is not a valid directory.

In VS Code, go to `File > Preferences > Settings`, search for `python.analysis.stubPath` and set it to `""` instead of `"typings"`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had also problems with VS Code pylance server crashing with MOOC exercises. I noticed that it happens when I have lots of exercise files open which I had already done. After a while when you do more and more exercises and write code in lots of different files, pylance server will crash every time. After I closed already done exercises in TMC plugin all seems to work fine. I think that there is a limit how many files pylance server can handle in same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I see in console output as follow:

```
2023-10-12 20:29:15.862 [info] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.vscode-remote/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.18.0-universal/pythonFiles/run-jedi-language-server.py", line 9, in <module>

2023-10-12 20:29:15.862 [info]     from jedi_language_server.cli import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jedi_language_server'

2023-10-12 20:29:15.867 [info] [Error - 8:29:15 PM] Server initialization failed.
2023-10-12 20:29:15.867 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
2023-10-12 20:29:15.867 [info] [Error - 8:29:15 PM] The Python Jedi server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.
2023-10-12 20:29:15.867 [info] [Error - 8:29:15 PM] Python Jedi client: couldn't create connection to server.
2023-10-12 20:29:15.867 [info]   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
```

So I installed `jedi_language_server` via pip and it works like a charm.